# NSInternalInconsistencyException when removing rows from a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I'm receiving an error indicating that I need to update the number of rows in my UITableView after I have deleted a row. I realise that It's because I've not updated the amount of rows in the UITableView, I'm just not sure how to make this change in the code I have below.

Any assistance is really appreciated.

!-- code

```
        NSIndexPath[] rowsToReload = new NSIndexPath[] {
            NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(1, 1) 
        };

        dv.TableView.BeginUpdates ();

           dv.TableView.DeleteRows(rowsToReload,UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);

        dv.TableView.EndUpdates ();
```

!-- error

Name: NSInternalInconsistencyException Reason: Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (3) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Dimitris thanks for answering my question. I ended up solving the problem by:

- calling the reload method on my UITableView

  ```
  NSIndexPath[] rowsToReload = new NSIndexPath[] {
          NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(1, 1) 
      };

      dv.TableView.ReloadRows (rowsToReload,UITableViewRowAnimation.None);
  ```
- in my UITableViewCell GetCell method

I removed the label, field and button that were included on the first load of the table. Since this screen in my app will be seen only once, when the user loads it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

Your code above is OK. However, you need to call it *after* you have removed the corresponding items from your data source.

For example, if you are filling your table view from a `List<string>` (myList) and you wanted to remove the first row:

```
myList.RemoveAt(0); // remove the item from the list first
NSIndexPath[] rowsToDelete = new NSIndexPath[] {
    NSIndexPath.FromRowSection(0, 0) 
};
dv.TableView.DeleteRows(rowsToDelete, UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic);
```

No need to wrap the DeleteRows call in a Begin/EndUpdates, as you only have one delete action to perform. That is used when you have multiple different actions (eg. DeleteRows + InsertRows) so that the animations are performed smoothly.

Comment: I'm not using a list. The items are added into a section which is added into a root element (Mono touch dialog). any ideas how I can cater for that situation?  /--- start code      return new RootElement ("") {       section,       new Section() {         (entryElement = new CustomEntryElement ("text")),       (StyledStringElement  = new CustomStyledStringElement ("text",delegate { triggerMethod(); })),       (StyledStringElement  = new CustomStringElementButton ("text", delegate { triggerMethod2(); }))      } ,        } ;